# Stop grass from flickering

Tags: rust

The grass in the game constantly flickers whenever I walk.  When I stand still, it looks as though I can't even see the grass, but the moment I start moving, what I assume is the grass starts rapidly blinking on and off.

Is there some way I can stop this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turn the grass off via the console;

1. Hit F1 to bring up the console.
2. Type `grass.on false` and hit enter

Problem solved!

Comment: As an extra to this comment, I've found that doing `grass.displacement false` after the above command gives me quite a significant FPS boost. Might be worth trying! :)

Comment: @nitsua In addition to grass.on false, or instead?

Comment: In addition to.